# Git add example for ignored files

Tags: git, security

How can I ignore file changes but can add or update its example, e.g. with `-f` flag. For example:
I have a secret file, e.g. `secret.properties` and I don't want to accidentally add this file to Git history, but I want other team members know how to setup the project.

Notes: I have checked out `git rm --cached <path>`, but it just completely delete the file from index. And `git update-index --assume-unchanged <path>` does not prevent other people from updating and also might produce conflicts.

Comment: Do you want everyone to have this file, but not on git?

Comment: I would like it on git but only update by force. E.g. I have a variable `MY_PASSWORD`. On Git, I want it be `MY_PASSWORD=changeme`, but locally I want change it to `MY_PASSWORD=s3cret`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file is either tracked or not, you can't have it both ways.

What you can do is ignore it, but add an *example* file, named e.g. "secret.properties.example" and then make your program refuse to run if "secret.properties" doesn't exist.

This is a very common practice with configuration files.

Comment: Thank you. I already created a feature request for this. Meanwhile I think we should accept what do we have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you firsly put these file in remote and local repositories. Than you need to add it to .gitignore file, so git will ignore all the changes you made in the file. It will stay `MY_PASSWORD=changeme` in remote repository, but locally everyone will change it and git will ignore it. So, if any new collegues will start, they are also able to pull that file as it is, but any changes they made will not affect the remote repo.

Comment: Thank you, but once the file is tracked it will be tracked all the times unless we remove it from the index regardless of the .gitignore files.